# Objective C Code for Creating Home Screen preview for ipad app

Tags: iphone

the problem is that how to create a preview of the home screen or the lock screen. because  i have seen such application, in which the user select the wallpaper and tap the preview button and it show the preview of the home screen or the lock screen when in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a preview with your user's settings for the home screen.
What you need to do is a transparent PGN with the home screen stuff (icons, dock, and status bar), and add it add it on your image.
Do the same with the lock screen (hour, date, status bar, and unlock slider).

You can find graphic objects for this here : http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/